# Why does IDLE *sometimes* require a space after an int

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

The IDLE shell (ver 3.10.5) allows this statement (note the omitted space between **2** and **in**):

```
2in range(5)
True
```

But it complains about these:

```
if True:
    2in range(5)   
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

def always_true():
    2in range(5)    
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

Why is the first one allowed, but the others not?

Answer (score 2):

In interactive python3.10.5 (on Windows 10), `2in range(5)` always returns True. Why does IDLE run on python3.10.5 show a different result?  IDLE does NOT compile or run the Python code you write.  However, its Shell uses a subclass of `code.InteractiveInterpreter` and the latter compiles interactive input with `codeop._maybe_compile`. (`code` and `codeop` are builtin modules that most people never use directly.)  _maybe_compile attempts to simulate the custom line-by-line behavior of interactive python mode.  This workaround is tricky and perhaps impossible to do exactly, especially as the details of parsing change.  I don't know yet how IDLE on 3.10.5 gets the 'invalid decimal literal' message as I have not yet reproduced it by directly calling compile().

To say a bit more: In current interactive Python 3.10.5+ (the development version of the future 3.10.6 release, all uses of `2in range(5)` emit "DeprecationWarning: invalid decimal literal" besides returning 'True'.  In 3.11.0b3+ and 3.12.0a0, the message has changed to "SyntaxWarning:...".  Somewhere from _maybe_compile to Shell, the warning is turned into an error.  In 3.13 or maybe later, the warning will become an error for everyone.